# How i can Read adjMatrix graph from inp text

Tags: java, file-io

I was trying to read adjMatrix graph from text it only read first line  but I encounter this error. Is there any suggestion please ?

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0 1 1 1"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
```

```
 public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        int row_num = 0;
       //InputGraph gr = new InputGraph("input.txt");
     //  Cells w= gr.copyMatrix();
     //   w.printAdjMatrix();


        try {

            String fileName = ("input.txt");
            File file = new File(fileName);

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            //get number of vertices from first line

            String  line = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("hi");

            //InputGraph.size = Integer.parseInt(line.trim());
            InputGraph.size=Integer.parseInt(line);
            InputGraph.adMatrix = new int[InputGraph.size][InputGraph.size];
            br.readLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < InputGraph.size; i++) {

                line = br.readLine();
                String[] strArry = line.split(" ");
                for (int j = 0; j < InputGraph.size; j++) {
                    InputGraph.adMatrix[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(strArry[j]);
                    if (Integer.parseInt(strArry[j]) == 1)
                        row_num++;

                }
            }


        } catch (Exception e4) {
            e4.printStackTrace();
        }
```

input text file

```
0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0
1 1 0 1
0 1 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

0 1 1 1 : This is one line. You are trying to parse it with Integer but this line is not completely integer as it contains spaces also which are characters.

To get the size, you can do something like this:

```
 String  line = br.readLine();
  InputGraph.size = (line.size()+1)/2;
```

Because if a line has x integers it will have x-1 spaces(considering that there is only one space b/w two integers) So, 2x -1 = size of line.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply but i wrote it gives with same error

Comment: Can you post the updated code please and also the updated error? Because I guess the error must have changed atleast for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a line specifying the number of vertices in the graph in the input file. This is why

```
InputGraph.size=Integer.parseInt(line);
```

does not work. `line` contains `"0 1 1 1"` here, which is more than a single integer.
You need to find the size from the number of ints in the first line instead. Furthermore I do recommend closing the input file after reading it, best using try-with-resources:

```
try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
    String line = br.readLine();

    String[] elements = line.trim().split(" +");
    InputGraph.size=elements.length;
    InputGraph.adMatrix = new int[InputGraph.size][InputGraph.size];

    for (int i = 0; i < InputGraph.size; i++, line = br.readLine()) {
        String[] strArry = line.trim().split(" +");
        for (int j = 0; j < InputGraph.size; j++) {
            InputGraph.adMatrix[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(strArry[j]);
            if (InputGraph.adMatrix[i][j] == 1)
                row_num++;

        }
    }
} catch (Exception e4) {
    e4.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your suggestion but Still                                                                    InputGraph.adMatrix[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(strArry[j]);                                                                    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

Comment: Then there seems to be a) a line starting with a whitespace or b) a int seperated with multiple whitespaces or c) a empty line in the input file... Edited the answer